# wp7 textblock inside listbox not showing

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox

this is the code that is driving me insane. It works great on windows 8(Snap View), but when I try to run the same XAML in my windows phone 7 app, it doesn't work.

**WHAT HAPPENS**
The app runs fine, but the problem is that the screen is blank. I have tried to add some background to the itemtemplate, and it does show up which means that maybe the databinding is working. But the content of the 5 textblock's doesn't show.

```
<ListBox x:Name="result_s" Margin="0,296,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="8,8,48,8" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="80">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="24" Width="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding coeff}"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="24" Width="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="4,0,0,0" Text="{Binding x}"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="24" Width="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,16" Text="{Binding xPow}"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="24" Width="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="4,0,0,0" Text="{Binding y}"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="24" Width="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,16" Text="{Binding yPow}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Here is the code behind

```
void func()
{
   ObservableCollection<Equation> answer = new ObservableCollection<Equation>();
   // SOME CODE GOES IN HERE, THE CODE POPULATES answer
   result_s.ItemsSource = null;
   result_s.ItemsSource = answer;
}
```

Please, can you see any reason this won't work.

Comment: It would be a good start to tell us how it fails to work. Nothing is displayed? An exception is thrown? An error message is displayed in the output window of Visual Studio (hint)? A dimensional rift is open?

Comment: @KooKiz I just updated the question

Comment: Your remark about the background is interesting. Could you try setting explicitly the color of the text (using the `Foreground` property) and see if you still have the same problem?

Comment: I did try changing the foreground color, but I still can't see anything.